# How to set value of public method variable to variable in a protected method?

Tags: android, variables, location, oncreate

I have a method to get the current location of a device and I want to set its value to be assigned to a LatLng variable in onCreate.I'm sure this is a simple fix but I can't think of a solution.Can someone provide a solution to this?

Its easier to explain this in the code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.journey_planner);

  //Get direction between from and to positions
  //want to set fromposition to point to the values of lat and long in below method onCreate

  LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(13.687140112679154, 100.53525868803263);
  LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(13.683660045847258, 100.53900808095932);   
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
  int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try making lat and lng class variables so your oncreate has access to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding this question correctly you would want to make your lat and lng to be class variables like @Clay said

```
int lat;
int lng;
```

Then you can set your fromPosition

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `lat` and `lng` variables from local to instance. In your class, outside the onCreate, say

`int lat;`

`int lng;`

Now your `LatLng` variables in your onCreate should have access to lat and lng